# Each string with quotes around it as own element in array

Tags: bash, shell, ls

I am trying to put every item that `result=$(ls -Q)` returns to array.

If I echo `result`, it looks like this: `"folder2" "folder space" "test 123"`. Notice that some of the items contain **spaces**.

How can I put each item around quotes in array (quotes must remain there). My desired output is:

```
echo ${ARRAY[0]}  --> "folder2"
echo ${ARRAY[1]}  --> "folder space"
echo ${ARRAY[2]}  --> "test 123"
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `mapfile -t ARRAY < <(ls -Q)`?

Comment: [Why you should not parse `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 3):

Use [*filename expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) like this:

```
ARRAY=(*)
```

Example:

```
mkdir test
cd test
# Create file with space in name
touch 'foo bar'
# Create file with newline in name
touch 'hello
world'

files=(*)

for file in "${files[@]}" ; do
    echo "name: ${file}"
done
```

Output:

```
name: foo bar                                                                                                                         
name: hello                                                                                                                           
world
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't parse the output of ls. Even with -Q, it is already broken. In my directory of toxic filenames, I get this:

```
res=(*)
for f in "${res[@]}"; do echo "file: $f"; done 

file: 1 file.tar.gz
file: 2 file.tar.gz
file: 3 file.tar.gz
file: 4 file.tar.gz
file: 5 file.tar.gz
file: abc3<foo.mp3
file: bb bb
file: dd dd
file: ff ff
file: file-mit"Quote"
file: m d.sh
file: regex=*a*
file: zeilen
umbruch.zip
```

My first answer and comment was wrong:

```
ls -Q
"1 file.tar.gz"  "3 file.tar.gz"  "5 file.tar.gz"  "bb bb"  "ff ff"              "m d.sh"     "zeilen\numbruch.zip"
"2 file.tar.gz"  "4 file.tar.gz"  "abc3<foo.mp3"   "dd dd"  "file-mit\"Quote\""  "regex=*a*"

result=($(ls -Q))
for f in ${result[@]}; do echo "file $f"; done 

file "1
file file.tar.gz"
file "2
file file.tar.gz"
file "3
file file.tar.gz"
file "4
file file.tar.gz"
file "5
file file.tar.gz"
file "abc3<foo.mp3"
file "bb
file bb"
file "dd
file dd"
file "ff
file ff"
file "file-mit\"Quote\""
file "m
file d.sh"
file "regex=*a*"
file "zeilen\numbruch.zip"
```

Comment: Why does it make new line if the file name contains space?

Comment: The update isn't wrong, per se, but it's not something you should *do*. You would get the same result from `res=*; for f in $res; do`; the array isn't being used to any real purpose. `${...[@]}` should *always* be quoted, or it is no different than `${...[*]}`. Instead, let the glob be expanded in the array assignment (`res=(*)`), then iterate over the correctly quoted result with `for f in "${res[@]}"; do`.